# KVO - observeValueForKeyPath not called when observing an enum

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I've used NSNotifications before but this is the first time I've tried to use KVO in Cocoa Touch.

My UITableView controller switches between a variety of datasources so I've encapsulated them in different UITableViewDataSource subclasses. I'm trying to have my view controller observe a specific one of these UITableViewDataSource subclasses and track an enum called `loadState` that reflects the models the load state.

I set the observer like this:

```
[self.siteUpdatesDataSource addObserver:self
                             forKeyPath:@"loadState"
                                options:0
                                context:nil];
```

From the debugger I can see that the observer is registered:

```
(gdb) po [self siteUpdatesDataSource]
<SiteUpdatesTableViewDataSource: 0x651e5a0>
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) po [[self siteUpdatesDataSource] observationInfo]
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x651dd70> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x651dd10: Observer: 0xc80f1e0, Key path: loadState, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x651dd90>
```

)

However, my observeValueForKeyPath method in my viewController never seems to be called. I set a breakpoint and nothing ever reaches it even when I validate that the enum has changed.

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                        ofObject:(id)object
                          change:(NSDictionary *)change
                         context:(void *)context {

   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I appreciate any thoughts on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't see any problem. Are you sure you change `loadState` property by calling synthesized accessor or by using KVC or manually (notifying about changes with `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:)`?

Comment: Thank you That did the trick.I'll try to experiment a bit more and figure out why the enum doesn't seem to generate the change. I am using synthesized setter and getter for the enum and updating through them self.loadState = kDataReady for example

Comment: Wait, you said 'did the trick' and next line you say 'enum doesn't seem to generate the change'. Did it work or not? I have no trouble with synthesized enum property.

Comment: Sorry, yes this worked. Later I found that I was setting my enum improperly in one spot. StackOverflow was unfortunately in read-only mode when I stopped back to updaet. Sorry for the confusion even though my problem was elsewhere this approach allowed me to trigger the observer event and helped me track down the issue.